# change all keys named LaunchNFW ussing batch

Tags: batch-file, registry

Hi I have a registry key named `LaunchNFW` which appears x amount of times in the registry.

I need to change the value of every instance of this key from 1 to 3

Is there a way of doing this with `reg query`?

I use standard windows batch for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"`) do (
for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`reg query "%%a" /v *`) do (
if "%%b"=="LaunchNFW" reg add "%%a" /v "%%b" /d "3" /f
)
)
```

You can use this to loop over every key in one hive. Just repeat the code for each hive that you want to check, and obviously change to the highest root key that the values will exist under.